# I need some guidance on how to do the following engineering scenario on Python

Tags: python, hierarchical-data

I have a manufacturing scenario where there are 8 different baskets. Each basket has different types of parts. 1 or more parts are picked from each basket to create a car and I want to create as many versions of cars as possible and this is my expected solution. Parts can be picked at random (eg: Part no 15 can be chosen before part no 5 from basket 2) from each basket but it must flow from basket 1 to basket 8 (eg: basket 3 cannot be before basket 2). Everything is text based, meaning basket 1 to 8 are lists and the car parts are text entries in their respective lists. Do check the small eg below for clarity. Can someone guide me on how I would create such a scenario where I can generate randomly arranged cars step-by-step? I have very basic knowledge in Python.

```
 1. Engine (Eng 1,Eng 2, Eng 3)
 2. Body (Body 1, Body 2, Body 3)
 3. Seats (Seat 1, Seat 2, Seat 3)
 4. Solution (eng 1+body 3+seat 1+seat3), (eng 1+body 1+seat 1)...,(eng n+body n+seat n)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of code to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to generate all combinations, one of the ways to solve this is using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
import itertools
engines = ['Engine 1', 'Engine 2', 'Engine 3']
bodies = ['Body 1' ,'Body 2']
seats = ['Seats 1', 'Seats 2']
cars = itertools.product(engines, bodies, seats)

for car in cars:
    print(car)
```

This will yield

```
('Engine 1', 'Body 1', 'Seats 1')
('Engine 1', 'Body 1', 'Seats 2')
('Engine 1', 'Body 2', 'Seats 1')
('Engine 1', 'Body 2', 'Seats 2')
('Engine 2', 'Body 1', 'Seats 1')
('Engine 2', 'Body 1', 'Seats 2')
('Engine 2', 'Body 2', 'Seats 1')
('Engine 2', 'Body 2', 'Seats 2')
('Engine 3', 'Body 1', 'Seats 1')
('Engine 3', 'Body 1', 'Seats 2')
('Engine 3', 'Body 2', 'Seats 1')
('Engine 3', 'Body 2', 'Seats 2')
```

If you look at the itertools page, you'll find the following recipe for random product generation

```
import random

def random_product(*args, repeat=1):
    "Random selection from itertools.product(*args, **kwds)"
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    return tuple(random.choice(pool) for pool in pools)
```

Calling this with args for parts

```
 random_product(engines, bodies, seats)
```

Will return a randomly generated car

```
('Engine 2', 'Body 1', 'Seats 2')
```

Comment: Itertools was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!